# Distribute webclient calls on multiple machines in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-ec2, spring-webflux

My requirement is to call a webservice that returns a list of values and then call another service with all those values .

I am using Spring Webflux for the api calls . Now if I have multiple machines deployed in cloud how can I ensure that the api calls are distributed among machines in AWS and I case of a failure response I can store it and retry.

Comment: AWS has support for load balancers. That would be the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just described Amazon SQS. https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

- Setup an SQS queue
- When you make the initial call, put the values into the SQS queue
- Have your servers poll the SQS queue for work

For failing response

- Create a [dead letter queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html)
- When response fails, add the value to the dead letter queue